# How can I redirect user to his directory when he enters his ID

Tags: php, html

Can anybody help me in making a input box where user enters his id and when he clicks on continue he will be redirected to his id folder on my website.
Like this: user opens website example.com and enters his id and click on continue then he will be redirected to exaple.com/(user id).

Comment: This is not proper way to ask question  refer the following  for how to ask questionlink.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html Code :

```
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
<button name="contiueButton" id="contiueButton"> Continue </button>
```

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#contiueButton").on("click",function(){      
       var userName = $("#userName").val();
       //validate username like check empty, check exist in db 
       var url ="exaple.com/"+userName;
       window.location.href = url; 
    });
});
```

Comment: I have implemented it here ( https://www.rmjtechnologies.net/demo/homeautomation/  ) but it is not working can you please check it ?

Comment: you need to write the code inside document ready function.Please check the above code,is it working or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$userid = $_GET['id'];
mkdir($userid, 0700); // to create new directory
header("location=example.com/".$userid."/"); // to redirect
```

Happy Coding...